# Airflow - How to configure that all DAG's tasks run in 1 worker

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG with 2 tasks:
`download_file_from_ftp >> transform_file`

My concern is that tasks can be performed on different workers.The file will be downloaded on the first worker and will be transformed on another worker. An error will occur because the file is missing on the second worker. Is it possible to configure the dag that all tasks are performed on one worker?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice. Even if you will find a work around it will be very unreliable.

In general, if your executor allows this - you can configure tasks to execute on a specific worker type. For example in CeleryExecutor you can set tasks to a specific Queue. Assuming there is only 1 worker consuming from that queue then your tasks will be executed on the same worker **BUT** the fact that it's 1 worker doesn't mean it will be the same machine. It highly depended on the infrastructure that you use. For example: when you restart your machines do you get the exact same machine or new one is spawned?

I highly advise you - don't go down this road.

To solve your issue either download the file to shared disk space like S3, Google cloud storage, etc... then all workers can read the file as it's stored in cloud or combine the download and transform into a single operator thus both actions are executed together.